# Seekbar progress update

Tags: android, seekbar

**Background:** I have one activity, with a Textview and a button. Clicking the button runs `SetValue()` which opens a dialog that contains a Seekbar, which in turn sets the value for the textview. Here's the code:

```
    public void SetValue(View view){
    ShowDialog();
    }


    public void ShowDialog() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(this);
    int value = 0;
    try {
        value = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
       System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
    } 

    seek.setProgress(value);
    seek.setMax(100);
    popDialog.setView(seek);
    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
    //Update textview value
    tv.setText("Value : " + progress);
    }
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    // Button 
    popDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            }
            });
    popDialog.create();
    popDialog.show();
    }
```

So it works fine, displaying the initial textview progress, and lets me update it with the seekbar.

**Problem:** 
After initially setting the value, if I try to use the method again to change the text, the progress on the seekbar starts at 0 every time, when it should be at the previously selected value/current textview value.

Also, I can set a max value for the bar, can I set a min value? Ie -100? How do I set a range for the seekbar?

Thanks for all advice!

**Update 1:**  I initialized the variable at the start of the class, so that eliminated the `int value = 0;` line, but the problem persists - the seekbar always opens with the progress at the original text value of the textview.

Comment: How do I define a range then? Not possible?

Comment: What do you mean "the progress bar always **opens** with the progress at the original text value of the TextView"? Do you mean you re-enter some page and the seek bar value has changed?

Comment: When I open the dialogue, the seekbar opens correctly the first time -  showing progress at the original value of the textview. Selecting value with the seekbar and closing it correctly changes the value of the textview. Re-opening the dialog, however, displays the seekbar at the value of the textview before it was changed.

Comment: You never persist the value of the `SeekBar` anywhere - `seek.setProgress(value);` will _always_ set it to be the original value of whatever you've got set in that `TextView`. Have you looked into SharedPreferences?

Comment: Who downvoted? Look at the proper fortmatting and clear description!

Comment: But when the textview value changes to the new value via `seek.setProgress(value)`, shouldn't it be reading the changed value the next time the dialog opens? I have looked into SharedPreferences and it's my next step, I was just hoping it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Where would it store it/read it from? And say it did persist it automatically - how would you retrieve that elsewhere? You definitely need to persist it yourself. I'll post some sample code to get you going.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the direction and the help, I certainly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to persist your value when the user finishes 'seeking' the `SeekBar`. We do this in `onStopTrackingTouch`:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
    //Update textview value
    tv.setText("Value : " + progress);
}
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // Update your preferences only when the user has finished moving the seek bar
    SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefsFilename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Don't forget to call commit() when changing preferences.
    prefs.edit().putInt("seekBarValue", seekBar.getProgress()).commit();
}
```

Now you want to display this persisted value whenever the dialog is created - so you'll need to retrieve it. You can do this like this:

```
int value = 0;
SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("mySharedPrefsFilename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
value = prefs.getInt("seekBarValue", 0); // 0 is default

seek.setProgress(value);

// You also need to update your TextView to show the saved value
tv.setText("Value : " + value);
```

You can wrap the access to the `SharedPreferences` in a class; this is one way to ensure you're using the same preferences file name (`"mySharedPrefsFilename"` in this example) and the same preference keys to store/retrieve the value (`"seekbarValue"` in this example).

Comment: It works well, and  is a fairly easy way to do it. I'll post a few questions about turning this into a separate class, and getting it into a database so it's there after closing the app and opening it back up.

Comment: Settings stored in `SharedPreferences` will persist across app instances. They'll only disappear if you call [`Editor.clear()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) or if you uninstall the app.

Comment: Really? Using the displayed code, when I leave the app and return, the data persists, but if I close it via the "Recents" button, the data resets when I restart the app.

Comment: That's really odd, I'm not sure what's going on there as this should definitely persist.